# Android data binding class not creating

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

For my android app, I am using data binding and it was performing well. When I have added some Onclick code on a ImageView and a button, it starts giving problem. Here is my code.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="isLoading"
        type="boolean" />

    <import type="android.view.View" />

    <variable
        name="hasCategory"
        type="boolean" />

    <variable
        name="categoryViewModel"
        type="com.test.viewmodel.CategoriesViewModel" />
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    ..................................
..................................

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:onClick="@{() -> categoryViewModel.deleteAllCategory()}"
        android:text="DELETE ALL"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/searchButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**item_category.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="category"
            type="com.test.db.entity.Category" />

        <variable
            name="categoryClickCallback"
            type="com.test.ui.CategoryAdapter.CategoryClickCallback" />
    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...........................................
    ..................................................


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/deleteImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:onClick="@{() ->  categoryClickCallback.onClickDelete(category)}"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon_delete" />

        ............................................
    ...........................................

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Those are only the two Views where changes has been done. Here is error:

*Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.*

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125)

It will be helpful if anyone help me to find the error(s).

Comment: The error you posted doesn't reveal anything regarding databinding error. Check the `Gradle Console` tab on the bottom - right corner of android studio. You can find the exact error & post it here.

Comment: Are you talking about Build window or anything else?

Comment: `Gradle Console` window. I am not currently on my system otherwise I would have shown you image point it out.

Comment: I got it. Thank you, I got the error, it is in Dao of Room.

Answer (score 0):

You try to move xmlns.

```
<layout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

<data>
    <variable
        name="category"
        type="com.test.db.entity.Category" />

    <variable
        name="categoryClickCallback"
        type="com.test.ui.CategoryAdapter.CategoryClickCallback" />
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ...........................................
..................................................


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:onClick="@{() ->  categoryClickCallback.onClickDelete(category)}"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/icon_delete" />

    ............................................
...........................................

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```